# Deploying to Wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: java, wildfly, jboss-weld, weld

I'm trying to deploy a GWT Errai application to Jboss Wildfly 8.2.0 Final, however, I am getting the following deployment error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade from [Module "deployment.app.ui-1.8.2.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 13 more

2015-03-25 13:05:39,466 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app.ui-1.8.2.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContextFacade
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade from [Module \"deployment.app.ui-1.8.2.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
2015-03-25 13:05:39,468 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "app.ui-1.8.2.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContextFacade
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade from [Module \"deployment.app.ui-1.8.2.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

It appears as if Weld incorrectly detects the application server as Tomcat.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should not deploy Weld as part of your application. It is already part of the application server. You should exclude Weld artifacts from your dependencies, especially weld-servlet.

Comment: Yes, I already have all weld references in my pom set to provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late post but your project requires class `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade` which the `ClassLoader` fails to find.

I am not too familiar with GWT so my knowledge on that domain is useless. Either you add a JAR containing the class mentioned above in your CLASSPATH or in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder or find a best way to deploy GWT application on Wildfly.